# FullCalendar - Save event start/end as milliseconds - format or not?

Tags: mysql, fullcalendar, milliseconds

- I have an application that uses FullCalendar.
- I want to save events to a MySQL Database.

I am using FullCalendar the prescribed way:

```
<link href='../fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='../lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='../lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='../fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '2016-09-12',
            navLinks: true,
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true,
            events: [
                {
                    id: 101,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2016-09-09T15:00:00',
                    end: '2016-09-09T15:30:00',

                },
                {
                    id: 102,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2016-09-16T17:00:00'
                    end: '2016-09-16T17:30:00'
                }
            ],

            // EXTERNAL EVENT DROPPED
            eventReceive: function(event){

                // loop event data
                for(var key in event){
                    console.log(key+" ------->"+event[key]+"\n");
                }

               // RETURNS MILLISECONDS i.e. '1498212000000' -> '1498213800000' 
               // WHICH MAKES ME THINK THAT THE MAKERS OF FULLCALENDAR INTENDED ME TO USE MILLISECONDS
                alert(event['start']+" -> "+event['end']);

                // SAVE EVENT
                SAVE_EVENT_VIA_SOME_AJAX(event['id'],event['title '], event['start'], event['end']);

            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

When researching saving FullCalendar events to the database; I see a lot of converting - of various date formats - back and forth with data in and out.

I am looking for the lightest weight, most accurate and straightforward approach to this.

---

The '`event['start']`' and '`event['end']`' are returned - by FullCalendar - as milliseconds.
This seems to be the - "lightest weight" and accurate (how can you go wrong with milliseconds and moment.js) - way to save to the database./?

If this is correct - then how should I now display these dates back?

FullCalendar does not seem to accept milliseconds in the `events:[]` this makes me think that maybe saving events to the MySQL as milliseconds, is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The event start and end dates in the eventRender method (as in most places in the calendar) are momentJS *objects* . So yes internally they store the timestamp in milliseconds, as you would, and that's likely what you'll see if you log the raw object to the console.

But you can output the date from them in any format you want - see https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/. So you could pass the date to the server in milliseconds, or something else unambiguous like ISO format.

But even if you passed the date to your server/database in milliseconds, that doesn't mean you are obliged to *return* it in the format. As long as you store the date in a DateTime field in your database, you can again use the date formatting functions of your server-side language (e.g. PHP, .NET, whatever you are using) to output it any way you like when retrieving it - ISO format is the one that fullCalendar/momentJS will most easily understand.